# SKMaps.jar FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, skmaps

I'm trying to initialize the SKMaps library for my Android project and I keep getting a FileNotFound exception that crashes the app. Here's the stacktrace:

```
05-22 11:33:39.631 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [Ljava.io.File;@3681ebc4/SKMaps/SKMaps.zip: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:72)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.a(SourceFile:160)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.a(SourceFile:126)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at com.skobbler.ngx.SKPrepareMapTextureThread.run(SourceFile:85)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
05-22 11:33:39.632 17610-17639/com.fedorparetsky.parcare W/System.err:  ... 5 more
```

I need to figure out/confirm where to put all the files in the project correctly and whether or not this line of code is properly loading the .zip file:

```
final SKPrepareMapTextureThread prepThread = new SKPrepareMapTextureThread(this, this.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null).toString() + "/" + "SKMaps/", "SKMaps.zip", this);
```

I'm not doing this through the gradle task that it says in their API guide but rather adding the jar to the build path and then supposedly preparing the maps with the SKMaps.zip file.

Comment: Was the SKMaps.zip included in your project's assets folder? Did you modify in any way the SKMap.zip archive?

Comment: Do I need to unzip the archive or make any changes to it before I put it in the assets folder? Could you please confirm the location of the assets folder so I know it is in the right location?

Comment: The location of the assets folder where I've put SKMaps.zip, SKMapsFull.zip, and SKMapsLight.zip is ProjectRootFolder/app/src/main/assets. Is that the correct folder?

Comment: Check the demo project for an working example

Comment: I am new to Skobbler and I have no idea where can I find SKMaps.zip. Any help would be appreciated.